# Tailwindcss. Css from tailwind.admin.config.js not overider tailwind.config.js. Using @config directive

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

I am using Vite and React for this Project.
I have a **tailwind.admin.css** like example in docs

```
@config './configs/tailwind.admin.config.js';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And this is my **tailwind.admin.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      secondary: '#999999',
      primary: '#000000',
    },
  },
}
```

But primary still `#0090DA` like the config in **tailwind.config.js**

In CSS file can find **tailwind.admin.config.js** so the link is right (if it is not right the terminal will  warning). So I try modify **tailwind.admin.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

console.log(123123123)
export default function a() {
  console.log(12312312312312312312)
  return {
    content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
      colors: {
        secondary: '#999999',
        primary: '#000000',
      },
    },
  }
}
```

And I found that there is no console. SO that I think for some reason it has not call the function inside the module when declare `@config './configs/tailwind.admin.config.js'`

Can you show me where I have gone wrong and how to fix it, please.

Where I have gone wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: The tailwind config.js should return an object, so the second code snippet is definitely incorrect, as it returns a function instead of an object, which could be invoked to obtain an object: `function a() {...}` and after `export default a()`.

Comment: The first code snippet seems correct. You can check if the rest of the code is not overriding the default secondary and primary colors and if it correctly specifies the value of the "content" property. I don't know your file structure, but typically the index.html and src folders are both located in a parent folder above the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution # 1

You should declare the configuration using `module.exports` according to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration).

###### tailwind.admin.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      secondary: '#999999',
      primary: '#000000',
    },
  },
}
```

#### Solution # 2

To use the `export` keyword, you need to use `.mjs`, which stands for Module JavaScript.

###### tailwind.admin.config.mjs

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      secondary: '#999999',
      primary: '#000000',
    },
  },
}
```

#### [`.mjs` vs `.js`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js)

> It is good for clarity, i.e. it makes it clear which files are modules, and which are regular JavaScript.

#### File Structure declared by your `content`

The file structure can be reconstructed from the provided code snippets as follows:

```
server
├── your-project
│   ├── app.css                      <--- 1. with your original @config
│   ├── configs
│   │   ├── tailwind.admin.config.js <--- 2. new config file (with your original content)
│   │   ├── src                      <--- 3. on your config file has relative path
│   │   │   ├── example.js
│   │   │   ├── example.ts
│   │   |   └── ...
│   │   └── index.html
...
```

If we consider the "general case", then this is indeed incorrect, but I am not familiar with your project and what you intend to create. However, I can show you where the problem might be. (Since I assume your `src` folder is not located inside the `configs` folder, and your `app.css` file is not outside the `src` folder.)

```
server
├── your-project
│   ├── tailwind.admin.config.js     <--- 2. new config file (with your original content)
│   ├── src                          <--- 3. on your config file has relative path
│   │   ├── app.css                  <--- 1. with @config './../tailwind.admin.config.js';
│   │   ├── example.js
│   │   ├── example.ts
│   │   └── ...
│   └── index.html
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already try the first solution first but it did not work. And the second solution is still not working. Is there anything I can provide more like tailwind.config.js,...

Comment: I tried your solution. If I didn't place the file in the specified path, the system indicated the following: `The config file at "./configs/tailwind.admin.config.js" does not exist. Make sure the path is correct and the file exists.` ---- If the file existed, it was read and the tailwind was built accordingly ---- I didn't see any console message displayed anywhere, neither in the faulty nor in the correct version, so it is not conclusive in my opinion.

Comment: Are the two colors it's trying to declare not overridden anywhere in the code? So, have you tried modifying the tailwind config file in a completely new and clean project to see what the result is there?

Comment: I will do this in a completely new project to see the result. Thank you.

Comment: The reason my code not  working is they have been overridden. Thank you for take your time helping me.

Comment: @PhongVũ, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.